# SQL selecting X random rows within top Y after ordering

Tags: mysql, sql

Using MYSQL, I wish to select

1) 5 random rows among the top 20 rows after ordering by "price" column

2) 15 random rows among the 30 next results (rows 21-50) after ordering by "price" column

What is the best way to achieve this performance-wise with SQL? Please note that the table contains around 1,000,000 rows.

The final purpose is to UPDATE a column (SET status=1) for these randomly selected rows.

Comment: SQL is just the language, every database engine has its own implementation. What RDBMS and version are you using?

Comment: Why does the price ordering matter if you get records at random?

Comment: MYSQL and PHP? Software version 5.5.30-30.1 - Percona Server (GPL). Client BDD version: libmysql - 5.0.96

Comment: @DavidStarkey Because I absolutely want 5 results among the top 20 priced items (with pure randomness, I could get 20 like I could get 0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested selects - should be quite fast in this situation

```
select * from 
(
select .... from table 
order by price
limit X, Y
)
order by random
```

Replace X and Y with the appropriate values

Note that depending on the particular RDBMS the "order by random" and "limit" clauses may differ! this is the MySQL way.

The most important thing is that the server will do the inner select first, which will return just 20-30 rows (depending on the limit clause) and you can sort it in random order in the outer select. If the price column is indexed this will be fast enough

Comment: Ok, I just read the added part about updating the status. You can do it in single query like this: update table set status where id in (select id from table order by price limit x, y) order by rand limit z. Replace x, y and z with the filtering number you need (0, 20, 5 for example)

Comment: I get this message when using your answer in comment: "This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery". Is there a workaround?

Comment: Indeed - there is a limitation documented that MySQL does not support LIMIT in sub queries (wasn't aware of that). Ok, plan B is temporary table. CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE l1 AS (SELECT id form table order by price limit X,Y); UPDATE table set ... where id in (select id from l1) order by rand limit z; Table will be dropped at end of session and is limited to the current connection only, so two connections will have separate tables

Comment: You don't temporary tables because you don't need `IN`. You can do the update with a join. `JOIN` is compatible with `LIMIT` subqueries.

Comment: I discarded the UPDATE+JOIN option, because I wasn't aware MySQL supports it but it does! Cool :) You can inner join the subquery select and do it this way, instead of IN clause. I am looking at http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21152/how-to-update-one-table-based-on-another-tables-values-on-the-fly - looks far better than temporary tables

Answer (score 1):

```
  ( SELECT dt.*
    FROM 
      ( SELECT t.*                    -- columns you need from the table
        FROM tableX AS t              -- your table name in place of "tableX"
        ORDER BY price DESC
          LIMIT 20
          OFFSET 0
      ) AS dt
    ORDER BY RAND()
      LIMIT 5
  )
  UNION ALL 
  (
    SELECT dt.*
    FROM 
      ( SELECT t.* 
        FROM tableX AS t 
        ORDER BY price DESC
          LIMIT 30
          OFFSET 20
      ) AS dt
    ORDER BY RAND()
      LIMIT 15
   ) ;
```